# Annotating Many2Many link works but only on SQLite (testing) not MariaDB (Production)

Tags: django, django-models, django-annotate

I am trying to annotate a model that includes a many2many field:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name = "%(class)s_name", related_query_name = "product_link_qs", blank = True)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Position(models.Model):
    place = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True) 
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 32)
```

in my admin I used `annotate()` to couple the information:

```
@admin.register(Link)
class LinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["product", "get_store"]
    list_filter = ["position__store"]

    ### extend by product_link_qs related name property to make field sortable in the admin
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(storename = Product.objects.filter(product_link_qs = OuterRef("id")).values("store__name"))

    @admin.display(description = "store name", ordering = "storename")
    def get_store(self, obj):
        return obj.storename or None
```

### only one product is linked to a position:

this works perfectly fine in **SQLite** on testing and **MariaDB** in production

### adding a second product to a link:

works on **SQLite** in testing, but gives: *django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')* on **MariaDB**

Comment: I worked around with putting a [:1] after my product filter: `qs.annotate(storename = Product.objects.filter(product_link_qs = OuterRef("id"))[:1].values("store__name"))` since the products of a Link can only come from the same store ... but I wonder how smart that approach is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the simplest way is to annotate it with the name of the store:

```
from django.db.models import F


@admin.register(Link)
class LinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['product', 'get_store']
    list_filter = ['position__store']

    ### extend by product_link_qs related name property to make field sortable in the admin
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .annotate(storename=F('products__store__name'))
            .distinct()
        )

    @admin.display(description='store name', ordering='storename')
    def get_store(self, obj):
        return obj.storename or None
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But if I do that, I would have to distinguish between my testing and my productive environment, right? Because SQLite does not support `distinct` IIRC? Or would you suggest this is the way?

Comment: @xtlc: SQLite definitely supports `.distinct()`. Only PostgreSQL supports `.distinct(..)` with field names, but we do not use that here.